# Programs always output 0

Tags: c, output, zero

I apologize in advance for any forum etiquette mistakes, this is my first post up.

Anyways, I have been writing code for the projecteuler.com problems, and now for the second time a program has, no matter what I do to try and fix it, returned 0. I'm coding in C.

** *PROJECT EULER SPOILER ALERT* ***********

The first program to have this problem is one that finds the largest palindrome that can be made by multiplying two numbers of three digits.

```
/* this is a program to find the largest palindrome produced
 by two factors of n digits each */

// test combos of n digit factors for palindrome product
// run backwards to optimize speed for finding largest
// design should work for user input number of digits to be multiplied

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

// declare and value vars
int n; // number of digits
int nsub; // for first while loop
int a = 0; // count down 1
int b = 0; // count down 2
int c; // counter
int d; // digit to be moved in palindrome checker algorithm
int e; // translates to true/false for palindrome
int t1; // number to be tested for... (palindromnity? palindromicness?)
int t3 = 0; // just another variable in my palindrome checker
int t4; // aaand another variable
int p; // current leading largest palindrome

// get user input for number of digits
printf("Please input the number of digits (<5 recommended) you \n");
printf("would like in the two factors that will be multiplied \n");
printf("to find the largest palindrome they can produce\n");
scanf("%d", &n);

// translate number of digits to count down start
nsub = n;
while ( nsub > 0 )
{

    a = 10 * a + 9;
    b = a;

    nsub--;

}

int i = a; // random int to avoid 'change in a' problem

// start of finding stuff algorithm
for ( c=0 ; c < i ; c++ )
{

    // loop to run through all b vals on one a val
    while( b > 0 )
    {

        t1 = a * b;

        // this will allow a check for an any digit palindrome
        /*  the program will remove the last digit (d) from the 
        (number that is hopefully a palindrome) and move
        it as the first digit in a new number to be compared
        to the original. before comparing the numbers with
        d moved to the other, it will compare them with d
        having been completely removed. this way even and odd 
        digit palindromes will register correct. */

        t4 = t1;

        while( t4 > 0 )
        {

            e = 1;
            d = t4 % 10;
            t4 = (t4 - d)/10;

            if( t4 == t3 )
            {

                e = 0;
                break;

            }

            t3 = 10 * t3 + d;

            if( t4 == t3 )
            {

                e = 0;
                break;

            }

        }

        // e = 0 means it is a palindrome
        if(e == 0 && p < t1)
        {

            p = t1;
            // p is the current leading largest palindrome

        }

        b--;

    }

    // resets at next a val with equal b val
    a--;
    b = a;

}

printf("The largest palindrome that is the product\n");
printf("of two numbers of %d digits is: %d\n", n, p);

getchar(); // extra for input
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

No matter how many digits I use, the program always says my answer is 0.

The next program to have this problem is one that is to find the largest product of five consecutive digits in a 1000 digit number. This is still a work in progress.

```
/*
73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450
*/
/*  this is a program to find the greatest
product of five consecutive digits in the 
1000 digit number above.
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

char str[1001] = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
int p; // current product
int g = 0; // current greatest product
int a=5; // counter

while( a != 1001 )
{

    str[a]*str[a-1]*str[a-2]*str[a-3]*str[a-4] = p;

    if( p > g )
    {
        g = p;
    }
    else
    {
    }

    a++;

}

printf("%d is the largest product of five consecutive numbers", g);

getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Thanks, I have been over it a million times and have no idea what it could be.

Comment: Have you used a debugger?

Comment: Hahah no I haven't. That's probably worth a try. Is there one you'd recomend? I'm running Windows 8.

Comment: I use Visual Studio 2012.  There's a free version called Express, and 3 levels of paid versions which you may be able to get access to through [academia](https://www.dreamspark.com/).  The free version will be good enough for your purposes, though.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding second problem:

```
str[a]*str[a-1]*str[a-2]*str[a-3]*str[a-4] = p;
```

this assignment seems reversed. In addition `str` is a string made of characters `'0'` `'1'` `'2'` which are not directly numbers, or at least

```
'0' != 0
```

since `'0'` is the character digit `0` which is encoded as `0x48`

Comment: You mean 0x30 if you're talking about ASCII.

Comment: Once i switched the assignment I got a real output. But I still don't get the correct answer. Could the '0's be being read as NULL characters or something of the sort?